# Implementing prime number generator using pipes

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am trying to implement a prime number generator using the sieve of Eratosthenes model shown in this [link](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/thread/#1)

The idea is to create processes that pass a set of numbers and each process eliminates multiples of the first prime number and passes the result along to the next process using a pipe.

So far I have gotten

```
/* 
*  Program to print primes in [2,35]
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <error.h>
int main()
{

    int pipefd[2];
    int pipefd2[2];
    int num;
    bool toggle=false;
    int rd_fd_n,wr_fd_n;
    int rd_fd_p,wr_fd_p;

    if(pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        printf("pipe failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(fork())   /* Initiator process */
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);  // close read fd
        int i = 2;
        while(i<=35)
        {
            if(write(pipefd[1],(void*)&i,4) == -1)
            {
                printf("write failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        close(pipefd[1]);
        wait(0);
        printf("parent exiting\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            if(!toggle)
            {
                rd_fd_p = pipefd[0];  // fd to read previous process
                wr_fd_p = pipefd[1];

                pipe(pipefd2);

                wr_fd_n = pipefd2[1];  // fd to write to next process
                rd_fd_n = pipefd2[0];
                close(wr_fd_p);        // important: close your copy of write fd when reading

            }
            else
            {
                rd_fd_p = pipefd2[0];    // fd to read previous process
                wr_fd_p = pipefd2[1];

                pipe(pipefd);

                wr_fd_n = pipefd[1];     // fd to write to next process
                rd_fd_n = pipefd[0];
                close(wr_fd_p);          // important: close your copy of write fd when reading

            }
            toggle = !toggle;

            int ret = read(rd_fd_p,(void*)&num,4);

            if( ret == 0)  // read prime
            {
                close(rd_fd_p);
                exit(0);
            }
            else if(ret == -1)
            {
                perror("read failed");
                exit(1);
            }

            if(fork())  // pipe the numbers to next process
            {
                close(rd_fd_n);     // close read fd to next process
                int prime = num;
                printf("prime %d\n",prime);
                while(read(rd_fd_p,(void*)&num,4) != 0)  
                {
                    if(num % prime)
                    {
                        write(wr_fd_n,(void*)&num,4);
                    }
                }
                close(wr_fd_n);
                wait(0);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of concerning things are I faced a few fork bombs but I identified and corrected it. But is it best to avoid this format of having forks in while(1) loop even though there is a terminating condition?

It is hard to debug this kind of code but GDB helps a lot. After each process forks, it waits on the child which creates a stack of processes all waiting on its child.
Is it better to avoid wait or wait only in the initial first process?

I try to close all file descriptors after I finish reading and writing to them but not sure if I missed a few.
Does leaving pipe file descriptors open, cause memory leaks, and how to verify if I am leaving them open during runtime?

Comment: im just curious what are you writing this sort of code for ?

Comment: Was trying some OS coursework from xv6 https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2023/labs/util.html

Comment: wow..its good resources for me to hone my c skill ..let me try andd debug your code